# Excel / DAX Function change [Value] on calculation

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the subtotals for a dynamic column in an Excel table. The data I get dynamically is formatted like text: `$1000,00`.

The usual function `SUBTOTALS(109; [Value])` won't work. This results in **0**.

Example Image:

[image: Table]

I have tried with `SUBTOTALS(109; RIGHT([Value], LEN([Value])-1))` and it didn't work.

Also I have tried with another function and way like: `SUM(SUBSTITUE([Value]; "$"; ""))` and it didn't work either.

Any suggestions on how can I format or change the `[Value]` in the final calculation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that you used an actual currency format ? The dollar sign would be irrelevant in that case, your explanation makes me think that you're actually using a text format

Comment: The format is text, I fixed the question.

Comment: Ok you probably expected this question but is there any good reason why it's formatted as text ?

Comment: There is no good reason but I get the information from a database with that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(RIGHT([Value];LEN([Value])-1);0)))
```

Array formulas must be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just enter.
You can't use some of the functions like RIGHT() or LEN() on whole arrays unless you use the array formula. You need to set the value when your formula returns error as 0, because it returns error when it finds empty cells in the target array.